# Armadillo, save with column names

Tags: c++, armadillo

Using the Armadillo library ([HERE](http://arma.sourceforge.net/)), one can easily save matrixes and other objects to a file. [THIS](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#save_load_mat) is the link to the section in the manual regarding the save functionality. It usually just dumps the data to a file.

What is not explicitly covered, is if one wants to save an object, where the file contains, also a header row, of say the column names for the data being dumped to file.

Which is the best way to achieve this?

Cheers.

Comment: have you tried writing your own code to achieve this?

Comment: No, hence the question, not sure which is the best way to do it.

Comment: @mtall I have added a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way, but this works:

```
void writeToFile(std::stringstream& ss, const char* name){
    string myString = ss.str();
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(name);
    myfile << myString;
    myfile.close();
}

void saveMatrixToFile(const fmat& object, const vector<string>& header, const string fileNameSuffix){
    string fullFileName = string("OUTPUT_").append(fileNameSuffix);
    if(object.n_cols > 0){
        printf("Saving : %s\n",fullFileName.c_str());
        if(header.size() == object.n_cols){
            std::stringstream ss;
            std::copy(header.begin(), header.end(),std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ss,"\t"));
            ss << "\n";
            object.save(ss,raw_ascii);
            writeToFile(ss,fullFileName.c_str());
        }else{
            object.save(fullFileName,raw_ascii);
        }
    }else{
        printf("Saving : %s, ABORTED\n",fullFileName.c_str());
    }
}
```